# Should links to scam sites be removed from questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently edited [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135402/recovery-of-bitcoin-stuck-in-limbo), and part of that was to remove the link/reference to a scam website. I have looked at the help center and such but haven't found an answer.

In my mind there are two outcomes of leaving the link to a scam site in a question:

- Other people Google "free-money.com scam" and come directly to the question/answer on this site. The best answer here clearly describes whether or not it is a scam.
- The propagation of the scam site's address causes more people to go there and also get scammed...

As a community, should we remove links to scam sites?

Answer (score 7):

I would say yes; remove any links to scam sites, but leave enough context for someone approving the edit or inserting their own 'delete item' request to see that it truly was a scam. ie: I suggest to leave the sentence grammatically as is, and replace with something like [external link removed], for clarity.

No point in having those sites move up Google's SEO by having them linked on Stackexchange.

Comment: Another option might be to add the link as code, so that is not clickable, but still visible, like `www.scamsite.com`